# Swift 2 language: AVAudio

Tags: xcode, swift2, ios9

Hi guys now that swift 2 has become I changed the few codes that don't match with the new coding language and the only thing that I don't know how to is the AVAudioPlayer. This is what I have:

```
var angryc:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("MSoundEffect", withExtension: "mp3")!
angry = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: angryc, error: nil)
```

Want me to change the "error" to "FileTypeHint" and when i change it says "Call can throw, but is not marked with 'try'and the error is not handled"
 Any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use try and catch, because Swift 2.0 has an new error handling. AVAudioPlayer can trow errors and you should catch these errors.

```
var angryc:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("MSoundEffect", withExtension: "mp3")!
do {
    angry = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: angryc, error: nil)
} catch _ {
    fatalError ("Error loading \(angryc): \(error)")
}
```

#### another method

When you are sure that the AVAudioPlayer won't fail, you can also use `try!` If it fails, your app will crash!

Your code would look like this

```
var angryc:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("MSoundEffect", withExtension: "mp3")!
try! angry = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: angryc, error: nil)
```

Source: 
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=106 at 39:30

[more info here about try catch](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-error-handling-try-catch)

[and here about AVAudioPlayer](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9097)

Comment: @MAURICIOHOYTE you're welcome! You could watch Apples WWDC video's here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/ and there are a lot of sites that can help you to understand the changes in swift 2.0 for example: http://www.raywenderlich.com/108522/whats-new-in-swift-2